# How to compose database queries in Scala?

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick

Suppose I define type `Fetch[A]`, which encapsulates a query to fetch data of type `A` from the data base. (It probably creates an SQL query for `MySQL` but this is implementation details).

Suppose also I have a few functions that create `Fetch[A]` to fetch blog data:

```
type BlogPosts = Seq[BlogPost] 

def recentPosts(blogId   : BlogId): Fetch[BlogPosts] = ...
def featuredPosts(blogId : BlogId): Fetch[BlogPosts] = ...
def popularPosts(blogId  : BlogId): Fetch[BlogPosts] = ...
```

Now I need to fetch all the `recent`, `featured`, and `popular` posts together. I would like to create a *single* query from those three queries above.

```
def threePosts(recent   : Fetch[BlogPosts],
               featured : Fetch[BlogPosts],
               popular  : Fetch[BlogPosts]): Fetch[(BlogPosts, BlogPosts, BlogPosts)]
```

Does it make sense ? Is it doable ?

P.S. Unfortunately I do not know `SQL` so I cannot give concrete examples of the original `recent`, `featured`, and `popular` queries and the resulting query.

P.P.S Does not `Slick` do exactly this ?

Comment: sounds like you just need to connect the different select statements with the union operator, provided they yield the same number and type of columns

Comment: Thanks. It should be easy :). What if one of the queries fetch data from another table ?

Comment: The number of tables involved shouldn't have any bearing on this.